# Do I have to have an entry in app.config for dynamic WCF

Tags: c#, wcf, binding

I create my WCF client dynamically in C# (WinForm - Desktop) with the following code:

My question is that if I supply an EndPoint that is not mentioned in my appconfig file it throws an error telling me it is not found.

Do I have to have an endpoint specifed in my appconfig for me to use this code:

```
BasicHttpBinding binding = new BasicHttpBinding(endPoint);
binding.SendTimeout = new TimeSpan(TimeSpan.TicksPerMillisecond * 5000);;
EndpointAddress address = new EndpointAddress(uri);
ChannelFactory<InformedMotion.Engine.wsMotion.ISync2Channel> factory = new ChannelFactory<InformedMotion.Engine.wsMotion.ISync2Channel>(binding, address);
wcf = factory.CreateChannel();
```

Can I adjust my code somehow so it is independent of any 'resource' file?

Thanks

Comment: You don't need any app.config to do WCF in your code. But we cannot help you with problems that are "it seems I need". My clairvoyance-over-tcp/ip device is still undergoing maintenance. For the time being, I can only help you with errors you post.

Comment: @nvoigt Hi, sorry for the delay. Been away.  There is an answer below which seems to address my issue. I am always keen to better myself here.  I am not sure what you mean with your comment though. I can amend my question if need be. Just need to know how/why? I think what you are asking is why I need to do this?  Well, it is because things can change and the app makes an initial web service call (from a known source) to get the configuration settings that will affect/change the rest of the apps communications with the web server as I will have several web servers you doing different things.

Comment: @nvoigt I forgot to say thank you for posting your comment :)

Comment: My question is: **What is your problem?** Do you get an error? If so, what does it say? All I can read is that *you think* you need an app.config file because you have problems that you don't explicitely tell. We can solve problems, but we need to *know* them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It expects an endpoint (whose name is within the variable `endpoint` which you didn't share in your code sample) to be in your config file.

Personally I think putting most of the wcf configuration into the config file is a good idea, because you're very flexible when it comes to changes.

But this isn't necessary. You can define the endpoint programmatically as you already did it. Just leave the `endpoint` variable out of the `BasicHttpBinding` constructor which isn't necessary and causes the lookup in the config file:

```
BasicHttpBinding binding = new BasicHttpBinding();
binding.SendTimeout = new TimeSpan(TimeSpan.TicksPerMillisecond * 5000);

EndpointAddress address = new EndpointAddress(uri);
var factory = new ChannelFactory<InformedMotion.Engine.wsMotion.ISync2Channel>(binding, address);

wcf = factory.CreateChannel();
```

Comment: Hi, sorry for the delay. Been away.   I agree with your points but I am in a unique situation here which cannot rely on an appconfig file..  I did not include the endpoint name as it did not seem relevant?  That was the point of my question you see.  Interchangeable EndPoint names (there is a reason for this and it is not in my control)

Comment: It works - thanks. Such a simple answer. I feel a bit thick now for not trying this myself lol